# What is the cause for Conditional Formatting to get jumbled up?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

For a while now I've been having a strange oddity when using Conditional Formatting. I created an Excel sheet for a separate department in my company to use which has the use of conditional formatting as follows:

[image]

All neat and tidy. However, after a while when I check back the sheet at a later date, I find my formatting to be all over the place.

[image]

I asked them how they entered the data and they said they keyed it in normally. I even tried to copy/paste, drag and drop the data and I still can't replicate the cause of it. Granted the function is still there but if I want to edit the conditions it's going to be a major headache with it all over the place.

For this issue what seems to be the most likely cause and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Most likely cause is inserting and/or deleting of cells within the CF area. Also some people tend to cut and paste a lot which may cause similar havoc.

Comment: If so is there a way to foolproof conditional formatting? I may not be able to stop them from cut/paste etc. but at least I want to save myself from a lot of tedious work if I need to edit it..

Comment: If the CF is the same on all rows, simply copy the first row that has the correct CF rule and paste special Format on top of all others. That should fix it.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to want to revert back to my original form. Is it possible to put it in VBA? That way I believe it cannot be tampered with.

Comment: Anything can be put in VBA. What happens if you delete CF rules from all rows except the first and then copy paste formatting? NB: I've seen people hiding rows they don't like because they don't know how to clear values. Been there, done that.

Comment: No it doesn't work that way. Even the Applied To field is all messed up. Case in point: `=$F$25,$F$39:$F$46,$F$9:$F$23,$F$27:$F$32,$F$48:$F$99999` These data are keyed in automatically via electronic measuring tools. Could the signal sent by them be messing with it?

Comment: I can't possibly know. Probably.

Answer (score 0):

Causes have been mentioned (moves, deletions and insertions) and a solution is quite simple: use whole column ranges. (Deleting rows, adding rows or moving rows all fit within "whole column").

Now that might give you an issue in your first 8 rows if there are values in those rows that might trigger your CF rules. (This is not often the case as many CF rules are to do with numbers and often label rows, admittedly rarely as many as eight, are usually text.)

So wrap your formula rules in:

```
 =AND(......,ROW()>8)
```

Tampering with the first eight rows could still be an issue but seems less likely and could perhaps be prevented with protection.